# how to delete manually SAML data from database in sugacrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new sugacrm user. I was testing SAML in sugarcrm. However, I inserted incorrecd data to sugarcrm SAML fields. Therefore, I cannot access to srm at all. I got following error message:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error parsing the request, Encountered error parsing message into its DOM representation That’s all we know
```

Is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the answer. I went to config_override.php file and set the following parameters to empty:

```
$sugar_config['authenticationClass'] = '';
$sugar_config['SAML_loginurl'] = '';
$sugar_config['SAML_X509Cert'] = '';
```

It worked for me.